# Defining parameters in a recursive function

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

Which of the two approaches for a recursive function seems like a better approach?

**Approach one**: `current_number` stores as min_number:

```
def sum_numbers_between(min_number, max_number):
    if min_number == max_number:
        return min_number
    else:
        return min_number + sum_numbers_between(min_number+1, max_number)
```

**Approach two**: `current_number` stored as a separate parameter.

```
def sum_numbers_between(min_number, max_number, current_number=None):
    if current_number is None: current_number=min_number
    if current_number == max_number:
        return current_number
    else:
        return current_number + sum_numbers_between(min_number=min_number, max_number=max_number, current_number=current_number+1)
```

> ```
> >> sum_numbers_between(1,3)
>    # 6
> ```

Is one approach considered better than the other? If so, why? (The second approach seems a bit easier for me to understand with the static `min_number`, `max_number` variables.)

Comment: Approach one would exhibit infinite recursion, since neither `min_number` nor `max_number` changes. Did you mean something like `sum_numbers_between(min_number + 1, max_number)`?

Comment: If so, the second one seems needlessly complex. Why should you pass `min_number` as an argument when it's never used except as a default value for `current_number`?

Comment: @chepner yes, updated that. Thank you.

Comment: I don't see what's wrong about the first one. Both max and min are static, it's inconsequential to the function whether it is called from recursion or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: I am treating this function solely as an example of recursion, not endorsing the use of recursion for this particular problem. I would actually implement this function non-recursively using a loop or the built-in `sum` function.

---

There's no reason not to use the first approach. If anything, I would modify that to handle any pair of numbers; you can define the sum to be 0 if the "minimum" number is in fact greater than to the maximum number.

```
def sum_numbers_between(min_number, max_number):
    if min_number > max_number:
        return 0
    else:
        return min_number + sum_numbers_between(min_number+1, max_number)
```

You can recurse in the other direction as well, counting down from the max.

```
def sum_numbers_between(min_number, max_number):
    if min_number > max_number:
        return 0
    else:
        return max_number + sum_numbers_between(min_number, max_number-1)
```

If you wanted to distinguish between a non-recursive entry point and a recursive helper, you could make use of a closure so that the recursive function only takes a single, changing argument.

```
def sum_numbers_between(min_number, max_number):
    def helper(n):
        if n > max_number:
            return 0
        return n + helper(n+1)

    return helper(min_number)
```

Here, `max_number` never changes, so instead of being an argument to the recursive function, `helper` simply closes over the value passed to `sum_numbers_between` to start. A benefit to this is that you can never "accidentally" pass the wrong value for `max_number` to `helper`, because it's not a parameter any more.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be a better approach to wind up the (inefficient) recursion sooner by having both ends move towards each other:

```
def sum_numbers_between(min_number, max_number):
    if min_number > max_number:
        return 0

    if min_number == max_number:
        return min_number

    return min_number + max_number + sum_numbers_between(min_number+1, max_number-1)
```

Comment: That's a minor optimization that wouldn't really be noticeable for a large range. You replace a single function call with an extra comparison that has to be made in *every* call.

Comment: @chepner, I cut the number of recursive function calls *in half*, by doing an extra comparison on each call.  Do you think the comparison is more expensive than function call?  My crude timing indicates my solution is 25% faster than your third one and mine can handle `sum_numbers_between(1, 1900)` but yours can't.

Comment: Like I said in my answer, I wouldn't use recursion *at all* for this problem. `sum(range(min_number, max_number+1))` would be faster *and* simpler.